# Example of topological space that is connected, locally connected but not path connected

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, path-connected

Is it possible to have a space that is connected and locally connected but not
path connected?

For example the closed topologist sine with its “limit line”
curve is connected and path connected
I am not to sure if is locally connected.

I am reading this URL
[favorite topological spaces](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/a-few-of-my-favorite-spaces-the-topologist-s-sine-curve/)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The cocountable topology on $\Bbb R$ is such a space

Comment: The Wikipedia article about the topologist's sine curve says right up front whether it is locally connected.

Comment: The lexicographically order square is such a space as is $\Bbb N$ in the cofinite topology.

Comment: Also the extended long line is another ordered example.

Comment: The closed sine curve is still not locally connected of course. And what the blog calls the closed sine curve is not path-connected. But that can easily be fixed.

Comment: One reasonable thing to do could be to check for [examples of such spaces in the $\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=connected%20%2B%20locally%20connected%20%2B%20~Path%20Connected).